# mysql2 ruby 2.3.1 install error using

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not very expert on Ruby. When I try to run my apps on local, it should be run well, but it's not. When I start server

```
rails s
```

it says

```
=> Booting Unicorn
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/lukni/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
```

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1

I need to launch my apps on my local.

Answer (score 0):

In your rails project folder you should have a file called `Gemfile`.

So, just add following line into this file: `gem 'mysql2'` according this error message: `Add gem 'mysql2' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord`

After adding that like do not forget about updating your gems via `bundle install` command.

And if you'll stuck with some issues after it's better to make all required steps from installation [guideline](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) of `mysql2` gem.